# The question count is way off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

On [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5606) proposal, there are two questions. But the label says there are seven.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, because of you choose off-topic tab

Comment: *[Slaps face...]*

Comment: Silly me... those tabs are confusing.