# The question tabs stay selected from question to question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

I go to a proposal, select the off-topic tab, then visit a different proposal and the off-topic tab is still selected.

I can imagine that this was a decision rather than a mistake, but it seems unintuitive to me.

Anyone else agree?

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54106/the-question-count-is-way-off

Answer (score 2):

This is the [by-design] behaviour across all of the sites. When you select a tab, you are selecting a *preference* for that to be your default tab. I admit that it is not as intuitive on area51 as it is on all the other sites, but I feel it is still a reasonable assumption. Especially for users who are familiar with the other sites.